# Creating a thread safe variable when using PLINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a list of items through which I loop using PLINQ statements to increment the total earnings of a specific user like following:

```
 double TotalEarnings = 0.0d;
_SortedList.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(5).ForAll(item => {
 TotalEarnings += Convert.ToDouble(item.SaleEarning);
 });
```

By using it like this, I always end up with a different value. I believe this is due to the fact that the declared variable is not thread safe. How can I fix this?

P.S. The _SortedList is a generic collection (List<>)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Sum` to get the total using PLINQ.  It will take care of aggregating the sum efficiently, and safely.

```
double TotalEarnings = _SortedList.AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
    .Sum(item => item.SaleEarning);
```